# Undefined variable - bootstrap pagination - Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, pagination

I have a controller that filter data from the database an send it to the view where i am using bootstrap pagination to show it on multiple pages... the data get listed on the view and every Everything work fine, but the problem is **when i try to go the second page i get this error:** `Undefined variable: filtredPosts`

this is the controller.

```
public function filter(Request $request){
    $query = Post::query();
    if ($request->country){
        $query->where('country','=',$request->country);
    }
    if($request->city){
        $query->where('city','=',$request->city);
    }
    if($request->type){
        $query->where('type','=',$request->type);
    }
    if($request->sortby){
        if ($request->sortby=='newest'){
            $filtredPosts = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
            $sortby = 'newest';
        }elseif ($request->sortby=='oldest'){
            $filtredPosts = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(9);
            $sortby = 'oldest';
        }
    }

    return view('posts.postDashboard',['posts'=>$filtredPosts, 'sortby'=>$sortby, 'country'=>$request->country,'city'=>$request->city,'type'=>$request->type]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `filtredPosts` is defined only if the `$request->sortby` is present.
If your request doesn't have a `sortby` key, this variable will be undefined.

You can solve it defining the variable before the `if($request->sortby)` check:

```php
...
$filtredPosts = $query;

if($request->sortby){
    if ($request->sortby=='newest'){
        $filtredPosts = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
        $sortby = 'newest';
    }elseif ($request->sortby=='oldest'){
        $filtredPosts = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(9);
        $sortby = 'oldest';
    }
}
```

Also, in your blade view, you need to pass the query string to the pagination using

```php
$posts->withQueryString()->links();
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide your pagination code on your blade, may be its something like :

```
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

You need to pass extra parameter with [`appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values) on Paginator method, like :

```
{!! $posts->appends(['sortby' => $sortby, 'country' => $country, 'city' => $city])->links() !!}
```

On **Laravel 7** or **above** version, you can call the [`withQueryString()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) method on your Paginator instance :

```
{!! $posts->withQueryString()->links() !!}
```

Comment: i added the extra parameter and it worked fine... thanks.